# Jest TypeError: Document.save is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, express, jestjs

I'm trying to write some tests for an Express app where I have an User model. One of my methods looks like this:

```
let user = await User.findById(req.params.userId);
user.name = req.body.name || user.name; 
user.password = req.body.password || user.
user = await user.save();
```

The code runs as it should, but when I test it, Jest complains:

`TypeError: user.save is not a function`

Right now I'm mocking my whole User model like this:

`jest.mock('../../models/User');`

I tried to mock the save function like this, but nothing changed:

```
jest.spyOn(User.prototype, 'save')
      .mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.reject('fail update'))
```

As I said before, the code runs fine. I don't get this error when I run the server.

However, there is one weird thing happening: when I run the tests I get this warning from mongoose

*Mongoose: looks like you're trying to test a Mongoose app with Jest's default jsdom test environment. Please make sure you read Mongoose's docs on configuring Jest to test Node.js apps: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/jest.html*

I read the docs and what it said was to set testEnvironment as 'node' on Jest config file, which I'm already doing. This is my jest.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    testEnvironment: 'node'
};
```

However I keep getting the warning.

This is my test script: 
`jest --watchAll`

Any help will be appreaciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are receiving that error is this line:

```
let user = User.findById(req.params.userId)
```

`findById()` is an asynchronous method, so you have to put the `await` keyword in the code, like this:

```
let user = await User.findById(req.params.userId)
```

As your code is not really awaiting a response from `findById()` that `user` variable is `undefined` hence `user.save()` indeed is not a function. You could try to print `console.log(user)`, and it'll be `undefined`.

To avoid this message "`Mongoose: looks like you're trying to test a Mongoose app with Jest's...`" you have to configure Jest in your `package.json`, like this:

```
"jest": {
  "testEnvironment": "node"
},
```

Comment: Actually the await was a typo, I have an await in my actual code. But your comment helped me figuring out - I'm searching for an user with no registers in the database. I'll try to mock findById return value and I should be fine. Thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome, did you solve that Mongoose message?

Comment: I'm glad to help. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.